# How to authenticate the user on his requests after login in django using TokenAuthentication from drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, access-token

I have implemented an endpoint for login, using the django-rest-framework and TokenAuthentication. What i want, is after the login, the user to be authenticated and can navigate on the website.
I know that any get request on any protected using authentication uri should contain the token in the headers, so that the user can be authenticated. Everything is fine with that, if i could do all the get requests adding the token manually.

But what i do not understand is, how can i add the token in the headers when for example the user manually does the request by writing the url?
Let's say that the uri */api/* is protected and requires an authenticated user.
The user logs in, and i save the token either on the cookies or in the localstorage.
Now the user does a http get request on  /api/. The token is not placed in the headers, so the response is: "Not authenticated".

So the question is, how can i add the token on any subsequent request after user logs in successfully? Maybe the backend could check the cookies for a valid token, but isn't there any better and safer solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

As I believe from the question you want to add the token to all API which is consumed by your client whether App/Web. So in both people prefer to store that token either in cookies or in local storage. Once user logged out api consumer also flush that key.